# How to get all the points that are drawn on the canvas and store it in a database using EaselJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

Is it possible to get all the points that are drawn on the canvas using EaselJS and store it in a database so that I can reload it for later use? I'm trying to make a load and edit version of this code: `https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ZNYPD/, can anyone help me?

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

// Add some text to draw on top of (also instructions)
stage.addChild(new createjs.Text("Click and Drag to Draw", "40px Arial", "#000000").set({x:200,y:200}));

// Set up the container. We use it to draw in, and also to get mouse events.
var wrapper = new createjs.Container();
wrapper.hitArea = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().f("#000").dr(0,0,800,600));
wrapper.cache(0,0,800,600); // Cache it.
stage.addChild(wrapper);

// Create the shape to draw into
var drawing = new createjs.Shape();
wrapper.addChild(drawing);

var lastPoint = new createjs.Point();

wrapper.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {

    // Store the position. We have to do this because we clear the graphics later.
    lastPoint.x = event.stageX;
    lastPoint.y = event.stageY;

    // Listen for mousemove
    event.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){

        // Draw a round line from the last position to the current one.
        drawing.graphics.ss(20, "round").s("#ff0000");
        drawing.graphics.mt(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);        
        drawing.graphics.lt(event.stageX, event.stageY);

        // Update the last position for next move.
        lastPoint.x = event.stageX;
        lastPoint.y = event.stageY;

        // Draw onto the canvas, and then update the container cache.
        var erase = document.getElementById("toggle").checked;
        wrapper.updateCache(erase?"destination-out":"source-over");
        drawing.graphics.clear();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obviously store each individual `stageX` and `stageY`, but we are talking about very large amount of coordinate pairs and also it can be tricky redraw everything from scratch by "parsing" these coordinates.

I would suggest a different approach for this. How about saving the drawing as an image file, storing it to the server, and then load it up at a later time on the `canvas`, like this:

```
//save canvas to image for latter use
image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

//load the image on a clean canvas
var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
stage.addChild(bitmap);
stage.update();
```

After this, your `canvas` should look exactly as before, and you can start drawing again on top of it, after all of your listener functions have been re-initialized.

Comment: Thanks Catalin Iancu for the suggestion! I already have a code for saving the drawing on the canvas but your suggestion of using bitmap gave me an idea. After saving the drawing as an image, on my edit page, i just loaded the saved image as a bit map onto the canvas and I can draw over it or even erase the previous drawing. :)

Comment: Yep, that's the idea indeed ;)